# How to trigger refactor operations in Visual Studio via code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I want to write a Visual Studio extension that receives a JSON file and trigger refactor operations on C# code in Visual Studio 2019.

For example, a list of commands would be:

- Extract MethodA to new class "MyNewClass1"
- Extract MethodB to new class "MyNewClass1"
- Extract MethodC to new class "MyNewClass2"
- Rename TypeD to "NewName"
  and so on.

I'm not familiar with writing Visual Studio extensions and I tried searching for this, but Google only returns results on "How to refactor".

Where do I start? What are the keywords of interest? What are the names of systems I need to extend? How does refactoring work under the hood? Are there examples?

Comment: Do you know how to create a simple extension for Visual Studio code?

Comment: @Chetan I don't, and my question is regarding Visual Studio 2019, not Visual Studio Code. Anyway here is a tutorial link: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. You might want to start writing simple extensions for visual studio and then move toward complex implementations. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2022) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-hello-world?view=vs-2022) and